# How to load Facebook chat history in KDE Telepathy?

Tags: kde, facebook

I've started using IM client for lower bandwidth usage - no images and other stuff.

However, a lot of people writing me refers to context written in older posts. Therefore I've got to go to facebook's site and load all unnecessary stuff...

So I would like to load few older messages when I open chat window. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Are you asking how to use a chat client such as Telepathy/Pidgin as a chat client with facebooj chat?

Comment: Nope, I'm asking how to load chat history, when I receive a message. I can receive new messages, send messages, but I don't know how to retrieve older messages.

Comment: Can you please expand your question then, I'm not familiar with the feature or what exactly you're asking for. Perhaps a screenshot or some examples? I use Pidgin as my chat client for Facebook, so I'm familiar with some aspects of what I think you're asking about but more info is needed.